# How to autosize html page into the WebView?

Tags: android, webkit

I have a android app, and I will load a local html page, but this page is too large to fit the `WebView`.

I have to control the horizontal and vertical controller to view the rest part of the page ,how to autosize the html page to fit my `WebView`?

Answer (score 2):

You should set next settings for WebView:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

May be you need to set viewport meta in html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=WIDTH_OF_YOUR_PAGE, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```

Also please check this post http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html. 
It's very useful.